# PL/SQL multiply Sql statements with if and then

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying to  write a PL/SQL Code which should ask **if something is there count it** and

**if tmp > 0**

so if the **object = 'VALID'**  then execute the rest of the sql statements  **if not skip everything** in the Then case.   When I Execute my code it dont execute the code.

```
  DECLARE
  tmp INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO tmp 
    FROM CDB_registry
    WHERE Status = 'VALID';

  IF tmp > 0 THEN

Col c.Status Format A6
Col Containers Format A20

Select c.Status, v.name as Containers
From Cdb_Ols_Status c, V\$Containers v
Where  c.con_id = v.con_id
And c.Name = 'OLS_DIRECTORY_STATUS'
Order By v.Con_ID;

prompt ****************************************************************************************



DECLARE
  tmp INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO tmp 
    FROM Cdb_Ols_Status
   WHERE Status = 'TRUE'
    AND name = 'OLS_DIRECTORY_STATUS';

  IF tmp > 0 THEN
    DBMS_Output.put_line('The Output  is true');
  ELSE
    DBMS_Output.put_line('The Output is wrong');
  END IF;
END;
/
ELSE
    DBMS_Output.put_line('There is no value');

  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You cannot put  sqlplus command like 'col' and 'prompt', ... inside a PL/SQL script. You can put all your formatting code (col, linesize, ...) at the start of the script, then do some SQL, ask for input, then some pl/sql, ....

Comment: but i  need the case if its valid then do  the other stuff when its not there he should just skip the  code in  the block

Answer (score 0):

Here's one options; I presumed some things (read comments within code) & agree with @gsalem's comment.

You commented that

> cdb_ols_status table does not exist when tmp < 0

It means that you'll have to use  dynamic SQL (**execute immediate**) because - if table doesn't exist, code won't even compile. I guess that's why you said that code I previously posted won't work.

```
DECLARE
   tmp  INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO tmp
     FROM cdb_registry
    WHERE status = 'VALID';

   IF tmp > 0
   THEN
      -- If this SELECT return only 1 row, you could declare local variables to fetch
      -- those values INTO them.
      -- Otherwise, it depends on what you want to do with them; if you'd just want to
      -- DISPLAY their values (which is what your SQL*Plus COL ... FORMAT commands suggest),
      -- then see whether a LOOP helps.
      FOR cur_r IN (  SELECT c.status, v.name AS containers
                        FROM cdb_ols_status c, v$containers v
                       WHERE     c.con_id = v.con_id
                             AND c.name = 'OLS_DIRECTORY_STATUS'
                    ORDER BY v.con_id)
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cur_r.status || ' - ' || cur_r.containers);
      END LOOP;

      -- The rest of the script should be ran because TMP value is greater than 0.

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'select count(*) from cdb_ols_status '
                       || q'[where status = 'TRUE' and name = 'OLS_DIRECTORY-STATUS']'
         INTO tmp;

      IF tmp > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The Output  is true');
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The Output is wrong');
      END IF;
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('There is no value');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it wont work for me because the cdb_ols_status table does not exist when tmp <  0 and in this solution he tries to count from cdb_ols_status also when tmp < 0

Comment: It means that you'll have to use dynamic SQL. I edited the answer; have a look.